# How to pass default start and end date to a form without using form controls to retrieve the data from http get ApI?

Tags: angular

I have a get API which has "Created date" as a field, now I would like to retrieve the list by setting the default start and end date to the from, where I should pass the start and end date as a parameters to get api (in backend start and end date date parameter were added)?

example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/read-local-json-file-hjfdfa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I can't see any form in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can send your parameters like this:

```
 var url = `productsList?startdate=${startdate}&enddate=${enddate}`;
 this.httpClient.get(url).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.products = data;
 });
```